# What does conditional "when: var | d()" mean in Ansible 2.5

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am unable to source from Ansible documents a clear meaning of a conditional such as `when: var | d()`. Is someone able give a clear explanation?

E.g. Below works whether inputing extra-var value from cli or defaulting to local ENV variable value:

```
vars:
  my_var: "{{ e_var | default(ansible_env.USER | default(False,true)) }}"
tasks:
  - name: Conditional check
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_var }}"
    when: my_var | d()
```

But this fails:

```
vars:
  my_var: "{{ e_var | default(ansible_env.USER | default(false,true)) }}"
tasks:
  - name: Conditional check
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_var }}"
    when: my_var
```

What is `when: my_var | d()` exactly doing? How how does it interplay with the `| default(false,true)` part in the variable declaration?

Answer (score 3):

`d` is an alias to the `default` filter. It is a Jinja2 filter, so head for [the  Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#default). They work the same:

> **default**(*value, default_value=u'', boolean=False*)
>
> [ ]
>
> Aliases: `d`

---

**Regarding the problem you are facing**, it is because Ansible processes a condition consisting of only a variable name differently from a more complex expression (which is passed directly to Jinja2/Python) ([the actual code starts here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/fb5bc5d5130e004d75ef28434f9fd415d1ae0cd8/lib/ansible/playbook/conditional.py#L125)):

- If the `my_var` variable has a value of `user01`, the conditional will try to find a value of `user01` variable and fail because it doesn't exist.
- If you just add a logical conjunction (which in common sense is redundant), Ansible will process the whole expression differently and it will work:

  ```
    when: my_var and true
  ```

In your case using another `default` filter in the expression is also redundant, but it prevents Ansible from trying to resolve a "nested" variable value.